# Taking a picture doesn't save the picture in the gallery

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-gallery, android-photos

I have a button, when pressing that I'll get an alertDialog to choose a pick from: Gallery or take a picture. 
When pressing take a picture and take the picture, the picture isn't being saved in the gallery. Why is this? 
I need the picture because later I'm planning to send it with a post to upload it to my server and add the string to the DB.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from gallery",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddBuilding.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }

                else if (items[item].equals("Choose from gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);
                }

                else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        btmapOptions);

                bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 400, 300, true);
                btnImg.setImageBitmap(bm);
                btnImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, AddBuilding.this);
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 400, 300, true);
            btnImg.setImageBitmap(bm);
            btnImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        }
    }
}



public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = activity
                .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting External storage. Instead save your image with this:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
                                    Bitmap, 
                                    Title, 
                                    Description);
```

This will save the image in gallery. See [insertImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

> **Parameters**
> <kbd>cr</kbd> The content resolver to use image
> <kbd>Path</kbd>   The path to the image to insert
> <kbd>name</kbd>   The name of the image
> <kbd>description</kbd>    The description of the image
>
> **Returns**
> The <kbd>URL</kbd> to the newly created image

Comment: Where exactly should I do this? `File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");` thought replacing this, but can't find `MediaStore`

Answer (score 0):

Its late but posting the answer for others.
Do this

File f = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraImages/temp.jpg");